# Why does "/" . date("Y") + 1 in PHP return 1?

Tags: php

Why does 
`"/" . date("Y") + 1` in PHP return `1`?

And a similar question, why does `date("Y") . "/" . date("Y") + 1` return `2011`?

I am quessing it has something to do with operator precedence, because `date("Y") . "/" . (date("Y") + 1)` does return the expected `"2010/2011"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep.  `.` binds more tightly than `+`, so:

```
"/" . date("Y") + 1
```

is parsed as:

```
("/" . date("Y")) + 1
```

The left side doesn't start with any numbers, so when you convert it to a number, it becomes 0.  Same with the latter:

```
(date("Y") . "/" . date("Y")) + 1
```

The left side of the `+` starts with 2010 then some non-digits, so when it gets converted to a number, it becomes 2010.  Then you add 1.

Comment: Also see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Comment: Ok, PHP's weak typing really got me here. I did not guess that "/" . date("Y") would evaluate to 0. I thought the result would be a string there. Tricky.

Comment: @konforce Well, yeah. Not sure I like PHP's behaviour in this case. I like dynamic typing, but I'm not as sure about the weak typing part. It's a bit weak sometimes... ;)

Comment: @Johan, Keep in mind that `+` will always cast strings to a numeric type, since it has a dedicated concat `.` operator. So `"/".date("Y")` does not evaluate to `0`... the implicit cast makes it do that. Given PHP's type juggling, what do you expect `(int)"/2010"` to evaluate to? I think the only reasonable answer is `0`. The part that may seem arbitrary is the order of operations itself.

Comment: @konforce `(int)"/2010" == 0` maybe not so surprising. I guess I just forgot about PHP's type juggling and the implicit cast. That and that I'm more used to `+` as concatenation operator. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score -1):

when you use point . thats mean that a string and after that your try to + this string whith a integer , that not logical

Comment: PHP automatically converts strings to integers.

Comment: @luqui, and if the string did  not began by a digit is converted to 0

Comment: Ok? I really don't get this answer... Would downvote it if I could.